# Remove object, with a common property, from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

Is there a way to remove an object from an array if a single property in that object is found in another object in that array?

```
const arr = [{
  car: 'bmw',
  notimportant: 'bla bla',
},{
  car: 'audi',
  notimportant: 'bli bli',
},{
  car: 'bmw',
  notimportant: 'ble ble',
},{
  car: 'golf',
  notimportant: 'blo blo',
}]
```

Also I would like to add a counter of how many duplicates there were

Expected result:

```
[{
  car: 'bmw',
  count: 1,
  notimportant: 'bla bla',
},{
  car: 'audi',
  count: 0,
  notimportant: 'bli bli',
},{
  car: 'golf',
  count: 0,
  notimportant: 'blo blo',
}]
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: @NinaScholz I do not know where to start to get that result, I tried new Set in the past and works well when the objects are identical, but when is only one property I don't  know how to compare it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the values for each car.

```js
const arr = [{
  car: 'bmw',
  notimportant: 'bla bla',
},{
  car: 'audi',
  notimportant: 'bli bli',
},{
  car: 'bmw',
  notimportant: 'ble ble',
},{
  car: 'golf',
  notimportant: 'blo blo',
}];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  ++(acc[curr.car] = acc[curr.car] || {...curr, count: -1}).count;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s uniqBy function to remove duplicates in an array by specifying a key:

```
_.uniqBy(arr, (e) => {
  return e.car;
});
```

[Here's the doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) if you're interested